# WS-Security C# "Error al consumir el Servicio Web"

Tags: c#, webservice

estoy trabajando en un proyecto que implica mandar reportes xml, mandar sobres xml, realizar consultas de estado en xml, todo esto vía WS-Security.
El proyecto o estoy realizando en Visual 2019 comunity C# y paralelamente realizo las pruebas con SoapUI.

Si realizo las pruebas desde SoapUI con un certificado de tipo PFX definiendo en la configuración de salida el **Key Identifier Type** en "Binary Security Token", y marcando la casilla de verificación **Use single certificate for signing** (adjunto captura), logro realizar la consulta y el envío de información sin problemas.

Cuando realizo la misma invocación desde C# con el certificado PFX obtengo el error, "Error al consumir el Servicio Web", viendo esto lo que automáticamente pienso es que me falta definir en c# el **Key Identifier Type** y el **Use single certificate for signing** ya que si en SoapUI se lo quito el error es el mismo que el que me devuelve c#.

Les dejo parte del código para ver si me pueden dar una mano ya que en este tema de seguridad no tengo nada de experiencia y a ver dónde puedo configurar ese parámetro.

Dirección del Servicio: https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6443/ePrueba/ws_eprueba?wsdl

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 var WS = new DGI_WS.WS_eFacturaSoapPortClient();

        string ClaveDelCertificado = "popo.1";
        string certPath = "Certificado.PFX";

        X509Certificate2 Certi = new X509Certificate2(certPath, ClaveDelCertificado, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        WS.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = Certi;

        var xEnviar = new DGI_WS.Data();
        var xRecib = new DGI_WS.Data();

        string Reporte_cCFE = @"c:\pepe-e\Rep_1234564546546_20201214_38.xml";
        string[] campo;
        campo = File.ReadAllLines(Reporte_cCFE);
        xEnviar.xmlData = campo[0].ToString();

        try
        {
            xRecib = WS.EFACRECEPCIONREPORTE(xEnviar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

Muchas Gracias por su tiempo y ayuda

Comment: Por favor, indica la traza completa de error cuando intentas consumir el WS usando tu código

Comment: hola, estoy con el mismo problema pero cuando consulto el rut, vi que tu tambien intentaste con ese tema, podrias compartir el codigo de la consulta de rut ?